# Maximum likelihood classification- changing class colour with every layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, layers, classification, feature-class

I created a signature file, where I defined 4 different classes, which I named and coloured specifically.

When I try to use the maximum likelihood classification tool for other layers, the classes defined in the entered signature file have different colours and no names anymore.

It is very important, that the same classes within the different layers can be identified as same classes later on.

Can anybody explain to me, why that is so?

I´m using ArcMap 10.3.1.

Comment: Use integer field for classes. Assign names to 1st output and save as a layer. Apply it's symbology to other rasters